# Using strcat() with a char from a string?

Tags: c, strcat

I'm trying to append characters from a string into a new string. For the code below:

```
int main(void)
{

char s1[] = "cat";
char s2[] = "hsklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld";   

strcat(s1, &s2[1]);

printf("s1 is now %s\n", s1);

}
```

Why is the output catsklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld and not cats? Why is the whole string added, instead of just the 's' located at s2[1]?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `strcat()` takes two string arguments, and because `&s2[1]` isn't a character, its the string `"sklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld";`

Comment: Not only that, it's UB because s1 isn't large enough to hold any more characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since a char * is only a pointer to the start of a string; `C` supposes the end of the string is a `\0` character. So all characters are added until he meets the `\0` character

you suppose `&s2[1]` points to "s", (which is true), but since it is a char pointer, it points to the whole char array, until the `\0` character at the end. Try this for example:

```
printf("%s\n", &s2[1]);
```

which will yield:

```
sklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld
```

from the reference of strcat:

> Concatenate strings
>   Appends a copy of the source string to the destination string. The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.

**EDIT**
if you want to add only one (or some) characters, use `strncat`:

```
strncat(s1, &s2[1], 1 /*number of chars to append*/);
```

**EDIT2**
make sure your char arrays are large enough, as suggested by @PaulR:

```
char s1[32] = "cat";
```

Comment: So how would I add just the one character at some index of s2 to s1?

Answer (score 2):

Both arguments to `strcat` are pointers to `char` objects, and both are assumed to point to (the initial character of) a *string*.

For example, this:

```
strcat(s1, &s2[0]);
```

is equivalent to this:

```
strcat(s1, s2);
```

In both cases, the second argument is a pointer to the initial character of a string, which `strcat` uses to access the entire string up to and including the terminating `'\0'` null character.

But your program has undefined behavior. By declaring

```
char s1[] = "cat";
```

you let the compiler determine the size of `s1` based on the initializer. In this case, `s1` is an array of 4 `char`s (including the terminating `'\0'`). There is no room to append anything to it. Apparently when you ran it, it copied characters into the memory space immediately following `s1`, which is why it *seemed* to "work".

A working version of your program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char s1[50] = "cat";
    char s2[] = "hsklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld";   

    strcat(s1, &s2[1]);

    printf("s1 is now %s\n", s1);
}
```

Note the `#include` directives. These are not optional, even though you *might* get away with omitting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strncat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncat) instead of [strcat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s1[32] = "cat"; // NB: s1 needs to be large enough to hold additional chars !
    char s2[32] = "hsklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld";   

    strncat(s1, &s2[1], 1);

    printf("s1 is now %s\n", s1);

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9569cfdd2faa89de)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Because `strcat()` takes two string arguments, and because `&s2[1]` isn't a character, it's the string `"sklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld";`

So `strcat(s1, &s2[1]);` concatenates

```
"cat" + "sklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld"
```

Giving the result

```
"catsklsdksdhkjadsfhjkld"
```

If you want to append a single character you could do this

```
len = strlen (s1);
s1[len] = s2[1];
s1[len+1] = '\0';       // new string terminator
```

but you would have to ensure there is enough array (string) space available.